# Why string is empty after type conversion in this Code. Can any one explain this please?

Tags: python, type-conversion

Can you please explain why I am getting an empty string after converting int value to char?

Python Code:

```
s = "10"

for c in s:
    #doing rotation of number by 2
    val = (ord(c) + 2 - 48)%10
    print(type(val), val)
        
    #Convert int to str
    val = chr(val)
    print(type(val), val)
```

Output:

```
>> <class, int> 3
>> <class, str>
>> <class, int> 2
>> <class, str>
```

Comment: It's not an empty string. It is the string `"\u0003"` i.e. a string with a single unciode code point, 3. It is part of the control codes, which are "non-printable" characters

Comment: what exactly were you *intending*? do you understand what `chr` does?

Comment: You're probably missing a `+ 48` in the `chr` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is converting the numbers you get after your "rotation" into strings, but not into the digits you want to have. If you want to use `chr` to convert an integer between 0 and 9 into its digit representation, you need to add back in the offset to `'0'` in Unicode, `48`. You had to subtract that out earlier, when you converted the digit into its codepoint, now it's time to add it back on.

Try:

```
val = chr(val + 48)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't get an empty string, but a string, which contains no printable character, since chr(2), chr(3) correspond to STX and ETX control characters.

You might consider using `str`instead of `chr`.